# How to bring back WORKREP1 after creating WORKREP2 in ODI?

Tags: oracle-data-integrator

In my ODI studio, I had a work repository named as `WORKREP1`. I created a new work repository `WORKREP2` (and by mistake, selected the option ***without keeping the existing contents of WORKREP1***).

This replaced my WORKREP1 and I can see only WORKREP2 now.

[image]

Please help me on how to get back to WORKREP1 or, how can I bring back all the contents of WORKREP1 into WORKREP2?
Thanks.